# Android studio not showing my device even after enabling developer options

Tags: android, oneplusone, oneplustwo

I have installed one plus X drivers on my Windows 10
I am using One plus X android device with Android OS version 5.1.1 - Oxygen OS.
I have enabled developer options, enabled USB Debugging, enabled ADB over network.
My android studio is not showing my device.
How can I start android app in my phone ?

Comment: try in the command prompt: `adb kill-server`, `adb start-server`and then check if `adb devices` lists your device.

Comment: it is showing daemon started sucessfully

Comment: when u run app, in dialog `Device Chooser` , try resize `Device` tab

Comment: @ojas and what did `adb devices` tell you?

Answer (score 0):

your device is not showing means your mobile driver is not installed successfully.
use [adb driver](http://adbdriver.com/) to install your device driver in windows 10. then it work properly.

Comment: a device not showing up on adb could have a number of reasons, not just driver.

Comment: which version of android studio you use?